# Pandas dataframe cumulative sum of column except last zero values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a cumulative sum on a pandas dataframe without carrying over the sum to last zero values. For example, give a dataframe:

```
   A   B
1  1   2
2  5   0
3  10  0
4  10  1
5  0   1
6  5   2
7  0   0
8  0   0
9  0   0
```

cumulative sum of index 1 to 6 only:

```
   A   B
1  1   2
2  6   2
3  16  2
4  26  3
5  26  4
6  31  6
7  0   0
8  0   0
9  0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want not use `cumsum` for last `0` values in all columns:

Compare if row no contains `0`, shift mask and use cumulative sum. Last compare with last value and filter:

```
a = df.ne(0).any(1).shift().cumsum()
m = a != a.max()

df[m] = df[m].cumsum()
print (df)
    A  B
1   1  2
2   6  2
3  16  2
4  26  3
5  26  4
6  31  6
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   0  0
```

Similar solution if want processes each column separately - only omit `any`:

```
print (df)
    A  B
1   1  2
2   5  0
3  10  0
4  10  1
5   0  1
6   5  0
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   0  0

a = df.ne(0).shift().cumsum()
m = a != a.max()

df[m] = df[m].cumsum()
print (df)
    A  B
1   1  2
2   6  2
3  16  2
4  26  3
5  26  4
6  31  0
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [262]: s = df.ne(0).all(1)

In [263]: l = s[s].index[-1]

In [264]: df[:l] = df.cumsum()

In [265]: df
Out[265]:
    A  B
1   1  2
2   6  2
3  16  2
4  26  3
5  26  4
6  31  6
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use `last_valid_index`

```
v=df.replace(0,np.nan).apply(lambda x : x.last_valid_index())


df[pd.DataFrame(df.index.values<=v.values[:,None],columns=df.index,index=df.columns).T].cumsum().fillna(0)


Out[890]: 
      A    B
1   1.0  2.0
2   6.0  2.0
3  16.0  2.0
4  26.0  3.0
5  26.0  4.0
6  31.0  6.0
7   0.0  0.0
8   0.0  0.0
9   0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip all rows after the first `0, 0` row, get the first index (by rows) where `df['A']` and `df[B]` are 0 using [`idxmax(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
>>> m = ((df["A"]==0) & (df["B"]==0)).idxmax(0)
>>> df[:m] = df[:m].cumsum()
>>> df
    A  B
0   1  2
1   6  2
2  16  2
3  26  3
4  26  4
5  31  6
6   0  0
7   0  0
8   0  0
```